# c++ recv function is slow

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, http-post

I have a program, that needs to communicate with a server through a HTTP POST request and then receive the answer from the server. The send and receive code is in a loop and should be executed as fast as possible. My problem is, that the recv()-function needs about 500ms until it finishes. The length of the answer i receive is unknown.

```
if (send(m_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) != strlen(buffer))
{
    cout << "HTTP: Error sending:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    return "0";
}
const int buflen = 322;
char buffer2[buflen];   

recv(m_socket, buffer2, buflen, 0);
```

What can i change to decrease the time of the recv()-function to a few ms?

Here's the complete code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET m_socket;

int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

if (iResult)
    cout << "Error" << endl;

m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    cout << "Invalid Socket : " << WSAGetLastError() <<endl;

setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, "1", 1);

sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &clientService.sin_addr.s_addr);
clientService.sin_port = htons(80);

if (connect(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Connection Failure"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
while(alpha)
{
    if (send(m_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) != strlen(buffer))
    {
        cout << "HTTP: Error sending:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return "0";
    }
    const int lang = 322;

    char buffer2[lang]; 

    recv(m_socket, buffer2, lang, 0);
    cout<<buffer2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it's the actual `recv` function taking so much time, and that it's not a problem with the other end of the connection or the network?

Comment: Also note that just because `send` returns less than what you asked it to, it failed. On failure then `send` returns `-1` (what the macro `SOCKET_FAILURE` is defined as).

Comment: i recorded the trafic with wireshark and i get the response from the server after 4ms, but i send the next request about 530ms after the first.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the `recv` call was slow, just that your program in general is slow before sending the next request. You need to start profiling your code instead, to find out what it does and where any possible bottlenecks are. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no one is going to be able to do anything but guess (badly).

Comment: i added the complete code. If i comment the `recv`-function i send requests within a few ms. With the `recv`-function each loop takes 530ms.

Comment: You use `setsockopt` wrong when attempting to set the `TCP_NODELAY` option. You should pass a pointer to an *integer* with the value `1`.

Comment: And if the code you show is (part of) your *actual code*, then there's really nothing you can do about it, as the problem isn't in your code or under your control. And `TCP_NODELAY` is irrelevant to that issue by the way.

Comment: if i want to pass a pointer of an integer, it tells me "Argument of type "int**" isincompatible with parameter of type "const char *"" . Would `recv`be faster if i use a non-blocking instaed of blocking socket?

Comment: You need to cast the variable. If you see e.g. [this MSDN `setsockopt` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that the type for `TCP_NODELAY` is `BOOL` which in Windows is basically an `int`. At the end you will also see an example of how to use it.

Comment: If you use non-blocking sockets then yes `recv` will return quickly. But most likely with the error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.